# AVD emulator not working on android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

Ive just installed Android studio on my ubuntu machine and I cant get the emulator to work

Looking at similar questions i ran the commands `sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386` and `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

but in the directory `/Android/Sdk/emulator` the folder lib64 doesn't even exist ( which it should according to all the other answers)

Another Solution that was given was to go to The AVD manager and to then set the emulated performance to software but as shown below that option is greyed out in my machine 
[Picture of emulated performance greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pslZa.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Reboot to your BIOS and enable `Intel HyperV` or `Virtualization Technology` whatever is listed there. AVD requires virtualization to be enabled from BIOS to take advantage of performance enhancements provided. So enabling `Virtualization Technology` would surely enable `Emulated Performance`.